# How to add a imageView in the centre of a customView?

Tags: android, mobile, view, custom-view

I have a custom view that is a circle. Here is the code for my CircleView:

```
    public class CircleView extends View {

     private static final int START_ANGLE_POINT = 90;

     private final Paint paint;
     private final RectF rect;

     private float angle;

     public CircleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

         final int strokeWidth = 40;

         paint = new Paint();
         paint.setAntiAlias(true);
         paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
         paint.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);
         //Circle color
         paint.setColor(Color.RED);

         rect = new RectF(strokeWidth, strokeWidth, 1000 + strokeWidth, 1000 + strokeWidth);

         //Initial angle is zero
         angle = 0;
     }

     @Override
     protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
         super.onDraw(canvas);
         canvas.drawArc(rect, START_ANGLE_POINT, angle, false, paint);
     }

     public float getAngle() {
         return angle;
     }

     public void setAngle(float angle) {
         this.angle = angle;
     } }
```

and here is how I declare it in the xml layout of an activity:

```
    <com.my_package.ui.recording.CircleView
            android:id="@+id/circleView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
```

All standard stuff. This is how my custom image looks like

[image]

Now, I want to place an imageView in the centre on the circleView? Does any one know how can I achieve that?

This is ideally what I would like to end up with:
[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you don't want to re-invent the wheel, can maybe use a third party library like this https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView

Comment: Have you tried it with `<layer-list>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't set on using an `ImageView` and really just want to draw the bitmap in the center then have a look at canvas' [drawBitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%2520float,%2520float,%2520android.graphics.Paint))  method. This will allow you to draw it however/wherever you want.

Comment: Hello @StuStirling . Thank you for your answer. Your suggestion worked. Thank you very much for that. Only one thing... do you know how can I position the bitmap in the middle?

Comment: @androidenthusiast you would need to calculate that based on the size of the view as we all the size of the bitmap